# Mongoose does not populate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to populate one of my models but it does not work.
This is my Card schema:

```
const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  wrap: {
    type: String,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User',
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Card', CardSchema);
```

This is my controller:

```
exports.getCards = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
  const cards = await Card.find({}).populate('user').exec();
  
  res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    count: cards.length,
    data: cards,
  });
});
```

It does return the cards but without any user field.
The user schema is exported as "User"

Answer (score 0):

You have made a small mistake in defining the models while you referring the User Collections, remove the single quotes

The model definition should be as follows

```
const CardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  text: {
    type: String,
  },
  wrap: {
    type: String,
  },
  user: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: User, // Replace 'User' with User
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Card', CardSchema);
```